# What is an Encoded URI string?

Tags: java, android, uri

Here in the docs of Uri the description of [`parse()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String))
says

> Creates a Uri which parses the given encoded URI string.

What is an encoded URI string? Is it like this:

```
http://username:password@host:8080/directory/file?query#fragment
```

or this?

```
http%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40host%3A8080%2Fdirectory%2Ffile%3Fquery%23fragment
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you provide some context to your issue? What are you trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: I am just trying to know that what is a encoded string and does parse() method encode it further to http%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40host%3A8080%2Fdirectory%2Ffile%3Fquery%23fragment

Comment: @NitishChopra Yes, but *why* do you want to know this? What problem are you having?

Comment: Out of curiosity because I have to use the parse() method in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
http%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40host%3A8080%2Fdirectory%2Ffile%3Fquery%23fragment
```

For example you can use this code for encoding.

```
str = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
                .replaceAll("\\%21", "!").replaceAll("\\%27", "'")
                .replaceAll("\\%28", "(").replaceAll("\\%29", ")")
                .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~")
```